# 'Null' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => void' of 'f')

Tags: flutter, dart

Here we are fetching the id & msg from the model. I'm receiving this error `_TypeError (type '(dynamic) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => void' of 'f') at the`forEach((achat)```.

The following is the problematic part from home.dart :

```
Future<List<Chat>> _getAllChat() async {

    var result = await _chatService.getAllChat();
    // List<Chat> _List = List<Chat>();
    List<Chat> _List = [];

    if (result != null) {
      var Chats = json.decode(result.body);
      Chats.forEach((achat) {
        var model = Chat();
        model.id = achat['id'];
        model.msg = achat['msg'];
        setState(() {
          _List.add(model);
        });
      });
    }
    return _List;
  }
```

And here is the Chat.dart model :

```
class Chat {
  late int id;
  late int userId;
  late int user2Id;
  late String msg;
}
```

Comment: Check the type of `Chats`, it's probably a Map and not a List.

Comment: Also try to follow the good code style:
https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#do-name-other-identifiers-using-lowercamelcase

Comment: Can you add your json Response and complete ChatModel.